# Swift: Convert Array of Dictionaries to Array of String based on a key

Tags: swift, swift4.2

Following is my Array of Dictionaries and I want to get an Array of only strings based on particular key (`contentURL` key in my case).

How can I achieve it? I have came across `Reduce` & `Filter` but no one fits into my requirement.

```
(
  {
    contentURL = "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/1510232473240ab.mp4";
  },
  {
    contentURL = "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/151021804847312.mp4";
  },
  {
    contentURL = "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/151021536556612.mp4";
  },
  {
    contentURL = "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/151021528690312.mp4";
  }
)
```

> Expected Output

```
[
  "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/1510232473240ab.mp4", 
  "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/151021804847312.mp4",
  "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/151021536556612.mp4", 
  "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/151021528690312.mp4"
]
```

Comment: I have edited my question with expected output

Comment: Where is this part being applied here _"based on particular key"_?

Comment: `contentURL` is the Key

Comment: So your dictionary is like this? ["contentURL": "<value>"]?

Comment: ["contentURL": "<value>"] where `contentURL` is the key

Comment: What other keys are there in your dictionary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `compactMap`

```
 let array = arrayOfDicts.compactMap {$0["contentURL"] }
```

Comment: Why not just map ?

Comment: @Rizwan compactMap get rid of eventual optional values

Answer (score 3):

```
var myDict: [[String : String]] = [["contentURL" : "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/1510232473240ab.mp4"],["contentURL" : "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/1510232473240ab.mp4"],["contentURL" : "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/1510232473240ab.mp4"]]
let arr = myDict.map { $0["contentURL"] }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var stringArray:[String] = []
for (key, value) in yourArrayOfDictionary {
    stringArray.append(value)
}
```

Comment: stringArray is not mutable if you use let

Comment: yeah thanks for correction bro just wrote it unintentionally :D

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrayDict = [["contentURL":"fd"],["contentURL":"fda"],["contentURL":"fdb"],["contentURL":"fdc"]]

let arraywithOptionstring = arrayDict.map{$0["contentURL"]}
        if let arr = arraywithOptionstring as? [String]{
             print(arr)
        }
```

Expected Output : ["fd", "fda", "fdb", "fdc"]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use reduce:

```
let arr = [
    ["contentURL" : "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/"],
    ["contentURL" : "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/.mp4"],
    ["contentURL" : "https://d1shcqlf263trc.cloudfront.net/1510232473240ab.mp4"]
]


let only = arr.reduce([String]()) { (partialRes, dictionary) -> [String] in
    return partialRes + [dictionary["contentURL"]!]
}
```

More compact version:

```
let compact = arr.reduce([String]()) { $0 + [$1["contentURL"]!] }
```

Probably you weren't able to use reduce since you need to remember that subscripting a dictionary returns an `Optional` that is a different type than `String`

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use just `.map` in this case.

```
let array = arrayOfDicts.map {$0["contentURL"]! }
```

Comment: we should avoid using force unwrapping until we are so sure about the data is not nil in any case

Comment: yes but in this case "contentURL" value is available in this array of dictionary

Comment: As a standard practice, we should avoid. if the array comes from the server then your code might crash, so to safeguard your code we should not use force unwrapping

Comment: yes you are perfect, but i have given answer for this issue, thanks

Comment: You can use `compactMap` and avoid the force unwrap.